# Get the table name using schema

Tags: sql-server, schema

I have seen some query like this in a stored procedure

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION 'column_id', column_name 'column_name', 
         column_name + ' : ' + data_type 'column_nametype',
         data_type 'data_type',
         CHARacter_maximum_length 'SIZE'
     FROM information_schema.columns
     WHERE table_name = @TableName
```

but i found that information_schema.columns is not a table name and it is a schema, but how it is retrieving the data?? and how can i know the actual table name?What is the use of a schema??

Comment: Is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) unclear?

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views reside in the Master database on the server and are a special type of view that will retrieve data from your database context.  That is, although they are in the master database they will retrieve information for whatever database you are currently using.

Just like any other view you can see the source for these views.  In the particular example given it uses sys.columns, sys.objects and sys.types which are themselves system views.

Although views such as sys.types is a view to which the source code is available some of the system tables/views within it are not available for direct reference.  For example sys.sysscalartypes is not available to the user and neither is the system function sysconv.

The user of INFORMATION_SCHEMA views is not limited to SQL Server although the implementations appear to be platform specific.  For example MySQL has its own INFORMATION_SCHEMA structures.

The use of the old sysobjects (as opposed to sys.objects) system tables is discouraged because there is no guarantee their use will continue in the future.  It has to be said that INFORMATION_SCHEMA although generally useful doesn't always expose the level of information a DBA would require.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @TableName = 'tblTest'

    SELECT 
            column_id 'column_id', columns.name 'column_name'
           ,columns.name + ' : ' + types.name 'column_nametype'
           ,types.name  'data_type'
           ,columns.max_length 'SIZE'
    FROM 
        sys.columns
    INNER JOIN
        sys.types
    ON
        types.system_type_id = columns.system_type_id
    WHERE 
        objecT_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    ORDER BY 
        Column_id
```